# Windows phone app t9 predictive text

Tags: c#, windows-phone

I am working on a windows phone app, which is a dialer and I have few problems with the predictive text. Predictive text works fine but it's laggy and slow. My code is:

I've put a contact search function in the textbox's text changed event:

```
private void dialer_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            MainPage.DialerText = dialer.Text;
            contactSearch(MainPage.DialerText);


        }
        catch (Exception f)
        { 
            MessageBox.Show(f.Message); 
        }
    }
```

ContactSearch function code:

```
public void contactSearch(string str)
    {

        try
        {
            var digitMap = new Dictionary<int, string>() {
    { 1, "" },
    { 2, "[abcABC]" },
    { 3, "[defDEF]" },
    { 4, "[ghiGHI]" },
    { 5, "[jklJKL]" },
    { 6, "[mnoMNO]" },
    { 7, "[pqrsPQRS]" },
    { 8, "[tuvTUV]" },
    { 9, "[wxyzWXYZ]" },
    { 0, "" },
};

            var enteredDigits = str;
            var charsAsInts = enteredDigits.ToCharArray().Select(x => int.Parse(x.ToString()));
            var regexBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (var val in charsAsInts)
                regexBuilder.Append(digitMap[val]);

            var pattern = regexBuilder.ToString();
            //append a ".*" to the end of the regex to make it "StartsWith", beginning for "EndsWith", or both for "Contains";
            pattern = ".*" + pattern + ".*";

           SearchListbox.ItemsSource = listobj.FindAll(x => x.PhoneNumbers.Contains(str) | Regex.IsMatch(x.FirstName, pattern));

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
           // MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
        }
    }
```

This code works fine but laggy and slow. I need to make it faster. Please suggest some improvements. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

These solutions can improve it:

1- Don't use Try catch for repeatedly functions:
This can slow down the performance easily, instead try using if else

2 - Use an asynchronous Task:
It's great for not blocking UI and avoids lag and crashes but use a low delay time for your task e.g 50ms;

3- Use other collection types:
As i can see in your code , your dictionary key is int started regularly from 1.
So why don't you use a array or list which are much faster with more items.
Like this:
    string[] contacts =     {"contact 1","contact 2","contact 3","contact 4"};

Or even a list:

```
List<string> contacts =     new List<string>();
contacts.Add("contact 1");
contact.Add("contact 2");
```

Note that Changing collection type may increase performance only in huge amounts of data.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try first two suggestions but not sure about the third one though. Can you tell me how to do that?

Comment: I am using a list for contacts, in above code 'listobj' is contact list. Dictionary is a pattern for searching contacts when perticular key is pressed.

Answer (score 0):

```
        public interface ICellT9
        {
            void Add(string a_name);

            List<string> GetNames(string a_number);
        }

        public class Cell : ICellT9
        {
            private Dictionary<int, Cell> m_nodeHolder;
            private List<string> m_nameList;

            public Cell()
            {
                m_nodeHolder = new Dictionary<int, Cell>();

                for (int i = 2; i < 10; i++)
                {
                    m_nodeHolder.Add(i, null);
                }
            }

            public void Add(string a_name)
            {
                Add(a_name, a_name);
            }

            private void Add(string a_name, string a_originalName)
            {
                if ((string.IsNullOrEmpty(a_name) == true) && (string.IsNullOrEmpty(a_originalName) == false))
                {
                    if (m_nameList == null)
                    {
                        m_nameList = new List<string>();
                    }

                    m_nameList.Add(a_originalName);
                }
                else
                {
                    int l_firstNumber = CharToNumber(a_name[0].ToString());

                    if (m_nodeHolder[l_firstNumber] == null)
                    {
                        m_nodeHolder[l_firstNumber] = new Cell();
                    }

                    m_nodeHolder[l_firstNumber].Add(a_name.Remove(0, 1), a_originalName);
                }
            }

            public List<string> GetNames(string a_number)
            {
                List<string> l_result = null;

                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(a_number))
                {
                    return l_result;
                }

                int l_firstNumber = a_number[0] - '0';

                if (a_number.Length == 1)
                {
                    l_result = m_nodeHolder[l_firstNumber].m_nameList;
                }
                else if(m_nodeHolder[l_firstNumber] != null)
                {
                    l_result = m_nodeHolder[l_firstNumber].GetNames(a_number.Remove(0, 1));
                }

                return l_result;

            }

            private int CharToNumber(string c)
            {
                int l_result = 0;

                if (c == "a" || c == "b" || c == "c")
                {
                    l_result = 2;
                }
                else if (c == "d" || c == "e" || c == "f")
                {
                    l_result = 3;
                }
                else if (c == "g" || c == "h" || c == "i")
                {
                    l_result = 4;
                }
                else if (c == "j" || c == "k" || c == "l")
                {
                    l_result = 5;
                }
                else if (c == "m" || c == "n" || c == "o")
                {
                    l_result = 6;
                }
                else if (c == "p" || c == "q" || c == "r" || c == "s")
                {
                    l_result = 7;
                }
                else if (c == "t" || c == "u" || c == "v")
                {
                    l_result = 8;
                }
                else if (c == "w" || c == "x" || c == "y" || c == "z")
                {
                    l_result = 9;
                }

                return l_result;
            }
        }
```